# Briefest code to find vowels and print consonants

Tags: code-golf, string, integer

**Challenge: Read a string from user, print number of each vowel, then place all remaining chars in a line. Shortest answer wins!**

Output must look like this:

> Enter String: *Input*
>
> Vowel Count: a: *#*, e: *#*, i: *#*, o: *#*, u: *#*
>
> Remaining characters: *Vowel-less Input*

For example:

```
Enter String: LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!
Vowel Count: a: 0, e: 4, i: 4, o: 4, u: 3
Remaining characters: LrmIpsmDlrStAmtCnsctrAdpscngElt!
```

Comment: Edited to better suit the site. Yeah... Just browsing other questions and even taking the tour isn't much help. Gotta be a better way.

Comment: Yeah, that is something that I have [been complaining about recently](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9022/unspoken-challenge-rules). Your edit makes the post a lot better. The only other thought I have would be to add some test input and output like you had in the first revision. Maybe even some additional test cases.

Comment: Okay. I can certainly do that. And thank you, wonderful community, for being more forgiving than Stack Overflow to noobs.

Comment: Is the output format flexible? For example, can the output contain only the numbers (without the vowel names) and then the consonants in a different line?

Comment: No not flexible, this interface specifically.

Comment: Also, is the input format flexible? Rather than prompting the user, could I take the string as a function argument? (This is generally the default. You can override the default, but it's not recommended.)

Comment: No. It must be an input in this case, I agree, this is a little against the norm :)

Comment: Unfortunately I think this question will boil down to which language has the shortest compression of strings

Comment: You're treating lowercase `a` different than capital `A`?

Comment: Also, for future challenges, I heartily recommend using the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/42963), so you can elicit feedback before posting to the main page, and thus make your challenge even better. Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: This is missing a blurb about what characters will be in the input. Will the input include newlines, unicode, etc? From your example it seems like you might not want spaces.

Comment: The fun fact is that we are *trying* to be nice

Comment: @CalebWoodman I don't think it has anything to do with being a noob or not -- rather, restrictive input/output requirements on non-Kolmogorov challenges shift the focus of the challenge, so that instead of actually doing work on the interesting part, people instead need to account for the I/O requirements, which instead feels like drudgery. [Please don't take the downvotes personally](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8099/42963) (see the PostScript to Peter's answer)!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. [This](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/34388) might be worth reading. The main problem here is the cumbersome output format, which isn't actually the _interesting_ part of this challenge. Since no one actually gave a solution on how this can be fixed, here's my suggestion. Instead of the long output format, try to change the output format to something like `[1, 2, 0, 3, 4] \n LrmIpsmDlrStAmtCnsctrAdpscngElt`. Or something else involving just an array and a string :p.

Comment: Do capital vowels not count as vowels (i.e. are not counted and removed)?

Comment: You're clearly missing a vowel.. (`y`). You English people and their lack of 'y' as vowels.. *shakes head in disappointment*

Comment: For these purposes, no 'y', but yes, I believe in its vowelitude.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen. And *w*. Tsk. All the Welsh people must be feeling left out.

Comment: Um, crafting my solution-- vowel majuscules seem to be ignored. Is that correct? Otherwise the vowels should be a: **2** e: **5** i: **5** o: 4 and u:3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 62 bytes

#### Code:

```
”‡Á•Ë: ÿ”,”Vowelš‹: ”?"aeiou"©vy": "¹y¢««}", "ý,“«¶šÞ: “ª¹®-J,
```

#### Explanation:

There is a lot of string compression going on here. Here is a list of all strings that are compressed:

- [`”‡Á•Ë”`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCd4oChw4HigKLDi-KAnQ&input=) is equivalent to `Enter String`.
- [`”Vowelš‹”`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdVm93ZWzFoeKAueKAnQ&input=) is equivalent to `Vowel Count`.
- [`“«¶šÞ“ª`](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcwqvCtsWhw57igJzCqg&input=) is equivalent to `Remaining characters`.

To see how the actual string compression works, see the [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67457/34388) answer, or an even more elaborate explanation at the bottom of the [Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/121090/98677). Without the string compression, the code looks like this:

```
"Enter String: ÿ","Vowel Count: "?"aeiou"©vy": "¹y¢««}", "ý,"Remaining characters: "¹®-J,
```

Or a more readable 3-part version:

```
"Enter String: ÿ",
"Vowel Count: "?"aeiou"©vy": "¹y¢««}", "ý,
"Remaining characters: "¹®-J,
```

**Part 1:**

We first push the string `"Enter String: ÿ"`. The `ÿ` here is used for *string interpolation*. But since the stack is empty, implicit input is requested. The `ÿ` will be substituted with the user input. We print this with a newline using `,`.

**Part 2:**

We first print the `"Vowel Count: "` string *without* a newline using `?`. After that, we push the `aeiou` string, `©`opy that to the register and map over the string using `v` and do the following:

```
vy": "¹y¢««}    # Mapping loop

v          }    # The loop itself
 y              # Push the current letter (which is a, e, i, o or u)
  ": "          # Push this string
      ¹         # Push the first input again
       y        # Push the letter again
        ¢       # Count the number of occurences of that letter in the input
         ««     # Concatenate to one single string, (e.g. "a: 4")
```

This leaves 5 different string onto the stack, the stack looks like this now:

```
stack: ['a: 0', 'e: 1', 'i: 0', 'o: 2', 'u: 0']
```

We join each element in the stack with `", "` using `ý`. After this, we print it with a newline using `,`.

**Part 3:**

We first push the string `"Remaining characters: "`. We push the first input again using `¹`. We then push `"aeiou"` which we retrieve from the register using `®`. After this, we remove all letters in `aeiou` using `-` and `J`oin this with the `Remaining characters`-string. Finally, we output this with a newline using `,`.

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCd4oChw4HigKLDizogw7_igJ0s4oCdVm93ZWzFoeKAuTog4oCdPyJhZWlvdSLCqXZ5IjogIsK5ecKiwqvCq30iLCAiw70s4oCcwqvCtsWhw546IOKAnMKqwrnCri1KLA&input=TG9yZW1JcHN1bURvbG9yU2l0QW1ldENvbnNlY3V0ZXVyQWRpcHNjaW5nRWxpdCE).

Comment: I've seen answers with `05AB1E` a couple of times now, but like most languages on this stackexchange I don't understand a lot of it.. Which of the characters in your code-snippet are used for the words "Enter", "String", "Count", "Remaining", and "Characters"? I can clearly see the "Vowelš" in the code (with an `š` instead of an `s`..), but I'm clueless about the others. (If possible I'd love a complete description of the entire code-snippet.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I have added an explanation. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask them :).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clear and extended explanation. I know it's not just for me but also in general to others, but I really appreciate the afford explaining it in such a clear way. :)

Comment: This is every sort of amazing!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 165

Fixed error in output, thx @Neil
3 bytes saved thx @Dom Hastings

```js
a=prompt`Enter String:`.replace(/[aeiou]/g,v=>(V[v]=-~V[v],''),V=[]);alert("Vowel Count: "+[...'aeiou'].map(v=>v+': '+(V[v]|0)).join`, `+`
Remaining characters: `+a)
```

Comment: Needs a space after the comma, but I'm surprised you didn't use a template string with a literal newline character.

Comment: @Neil I was careless, with so many unnecessary characters in the output, what's one more...

Comment: A couple more bytes you can save, using a template string for the argument to `prompt(...)` and using `|0` instead of `||0`.

Comment: @DomHastings right, thanks

Comment: You need a space after the colon in `Enter String:`

Comment: @ericw31415 I don't think so. `prompt` add a newline anyway

Comment: Why do you use prompt instead of a lambda function?

Comment: @Bálint `Challenge: Read a string from user, `... the spec for input / output are strange enough, I take them literally

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 168 bytes

```
s=input('Enter String:')
v='aeiou'
print('Vowel Count: '+', '.join([a+':'+str(s.count(a)) for a in v])+'\nRemaining characters: '+''.join([a for a in s if a not in v]))
```

https://repl.it/CMzO/1

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 127 bytes

```
$_=<>;print"Enter String: ${_}Vowel Count:";for$s(a,e,i,o,u){print" $s: ".~~s/$s//g,$s!~u&&","}print"
Remaining characters: $_"
```

Many thanks to [Dom Hastings](/u/9365) (in a comment hereon) for 14 bytes.

Comment: I had a slightly different approach using a loop, can you use the same mechanism to save bytes? `sub p{print@_}p"Enter String: ";$_=<>;p"Vowel Count:";for$s(a,e,i,o,u){p" $s: ".~~s/$s//g,$s!~/u/&&","}p"\nRemaining characters: $_"` (note: \n is a literal newline!)

Comment: @DomHastings, many thanks, that saves a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

## PostgreSQL, <strike>295</strike>, 263 bytes

```
SELECT v "Enter string:", string_agg(r,', 'ORDER BY n) "Vowel Count:",TRANSLATE(v,'aeyiou','') "Remaining characters:"
FROM (SELECT 'LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!'::text v)s
,LATERAL(SELECT LENGTH(v)l)a
,LATERAL(SELECT c||': '||l-LENGTH(REPLACE(v,c,''))r,n FROM (VALUES('a',1),('e',2),('i',3),('o',4),('u',5))t(c,n))b
GROUP BY v
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8236/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║                  Enter string:                   ║         Vowel Count:          ║      Remaining characters:       ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!  ║ a: 0, e: 4, i: 4, o: 4, u: 3  ║ LrmIpsmDlrStAmtCnsctrAdpscngElt! ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Input: `(SELECT '...'::text v)s`

How it works:

- `(SELECT 'LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!'::text v)s` input
- `,LATERAL(SELECT LENGTH(v)l)a` - length of input
- `(VALUES('a',1),('e',2),('i',3),('o',4),('u',5))` - vowels with oridinal
- `SELECT c||': '||l-LENGTH(REPLACE(v,c,''))r,n` - calculate number of occurences
- `string_agg(r,', 'ORDER BY n) ... GROUP BY v` combine result
- `TRANSLATE(v,'aeyiou','')` string without vowels

**EDIT 3:**

Removed additional `LATERAL`, input moved to table.

```
SELECT v"Enter string:",string_agg(r,', 'ORDER BY n)"Vowel Count:",TRANSLATE(v,'aeyiou','')"Remaining characters:"
FROM s,LATERAL(SELECT c||': '||LENGTH(v)-LENGTH(REPLACE(v,c,''))r,n FROM(VALUES('a',1),('e',2),('i',3),('o',4),('u',5))t(c,n))b
GROUP BY v
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1b88/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: I'm still amazed how people use SQL for anything other than databases

Comment: @Bálint In all my answers I use SQL . In production I would not use this kind of code but as puzzle why not.

Comment: This would appear to hardcode the input and does not show the prompt required in the question.

Comment: *`Output must look like this`*

Comment: @cat Added version with table. `Output must look like this` with SQL (declarative statement) you cannot get interactive prompt.

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, 242 Bytes

For a moment, I thought that it will be longer than SQL... still a monster for such a simple task.

```lua
t={}x="aeiou"i=io.write 
x:gsub(".",function(c)t[c]=0 end)i("Enter string: ")z=io.read()s="Remaining characters: "..z:gsub(".",function(c)if x:find(c)then
t[c]=t[c]+1return""end end)i("Vowel Count: ")x:gsub(".",function(c)i(c..": "..t[c]..(c=="u"and"\n"or", "))end)i(s)
```

The job is done by the part

```lua
z:gsub(".",function(c)if x:find(c)then t[c]=t[c]+1return""end end)
```

Everything else is mainly for the purpose of outputing in the right format.

#### Ungolfed

```lua
t={}                             -- create an empty array
x="aeiou"                        -- list of vowels
i=io.write                       -- shorthand for outputing
x:gsub(".",function(c)t[c]=0 end)-- create a celle at 0 for each vowel
i("Enter string: ")              -- output some boilerplate
z=io.read()                      -- take the input
s="Remaining characters: "..     -- save in s the concatenation of this string
  z:gsub(".",function(c)         -- and the result of gsubing on each character of the input 
  if x:find(c)                   -- if the current char is a vowel
  then
    t[c]=t[c]+1                  -- increment its counter
    return""                     -- suppress it from the input
  end
end)

i("Vowel Count: ")               -- output some more boilerplate
x:gsub(".",function(c)           -- iterate over the vowels
  i(c..": "..t[c]..              -- output "l: #" appended with
    (c=="u"
        and"\n"                  -- "\n" if the current char is "u"
      or", "))                   -- ", " otherwise
end)
i(s)                             -- output the content of s
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python, <del>220</del> 201 bytes**

This is my first submission on codegolf so go easy. :P

```
def f(y):
  global x;c=x.count(y);x=x.replace(y,'');return c;
x=input('Enter string: ');print('Vowel Count: a: {}, e: {}, i: {}, o: {}, u: {}'.format(*map(f,"aeiou")));print('Remaining characters: '+x)
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
def f(y):
  global x
  c=x.count(y)
  x=x.replace(y,'')
  return c;
x=input('Enter string: ')
print('Vowel Count: a: {}, e: {}, i: {}, o: {}, u: {}'.format(*map(f,"aeiou")))
print('Remaining characters: '+x)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter string: LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!
Vowel Count: a: 0, e: 4, i: 4, o: 4, u: 3
Remaining characters: LrmIpsmDlrStAmtCnsctrAdpscngElt!
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You might be able to save some bytes by using Python's list comprehensions and unpacking them into the format function instead of calling each function individually: `...u: {}'.format(*[f(c)for c in 'aeiou'])`. Also, I think you can put the commands from a function on the same line right after the colon and it should work, saving some bytes.

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny It might be shorter to do `.format(*map(f,"aeiou"))`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>190</s> 186 bytes

```
(s,a=[..."aeiou"].map(v=>(s.match(v,"g")||[]).length))=>`Enter String: ${s}
Vowel Count: ${[..."aeiou"].map((v,i)=>v+": "+a[i]).join`, `}
Remaining characters: `+s.replace(/[aeiou]/g,"")
```

I just remembered that literal newlines are only 1 byte! Also remembered to golf something I missed before.

Comment: Why do you use RegExp(expression, modifier) instead of /expression/modifier?

Comment: I need to plug in the `v` into the RegExp. If I used `/v/g`, the v would be a literal string instead of the value of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 272 bytes

```
class L{public static void main(String[]v){String p=v[0],o="Enter String: "+p+"\nVowel Count:",d=" ",e="aeiou";for(char c:e.toCharArray()){o+=d+c+": "+p.replaceAll("[^"+c+"]","").length();d=", ";}System.out.println("\nRemaining characters: "+p.replaceAll("["+e+"]",""));}}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
class L {
    public static void main(String[] v) {
        String input = v[0], result = "Enter String: " + input + "\nVowel Count:", delimiter = " ", vowels = "aeiou";
        for (char c : vowels.toCharArray()) {
            result += delimiter + c + ": " + input.replaceAll("[^" + c + "]", "").length();
            delimiter = ", ";
        }
        System.out.println("\nRemaining characters: " + input.replaceAll("[" + vowels + "]", ""));
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- Input via program arguments: Save as `L.java`, compile with `javac L.java`, run with `java L LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!`

#### Output

```
Enter String: LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!
Vowel Count: a: 0, e: 4, i: 4, o: 4, u: 3
Remaining characters: LrmIpsmDlrStAmtCnsctrAdpscngElt!
```

Comment: I know it's a while, but you can golf it to **246 bytes** like this: `interface M{static void main(String[]v){String p=v[0],o="Enter String: "+p+"\nVowel Count:",d=" ",e="aeiou";for(String c:e.split("")){o+=d+c+": "+~-p.split(c,-1).length;d=", ";p=p.replace(c,"");}System.out.print(o+"\nRemaining characters: "+p);}}` [Try it here.](https://tinyurl.com/y9tpn7rf)

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>196</s> 149 bytes

```
$z=read-host "Enter string"
"Vowel Count: "+(([char[]]"aeiou"|%{$_+": "+($z.length-($z=$z-creplace$_).length)})-join', ')
"Remaining characters: "+$z
```

Takes input via `read-host` with a prompt, save into `$z`.

We then output a string literal `"Vowel Count: "` concatenated with the result of a loop/join through the vowels to construct the `a: #, e: #,...` string. This is done by taking the current string's `.length` minus the new string's `.length` after we perform a case-sensitive replacement with `-creplace` (i.e., how many did we remove). In addition, we re-save the result of the replace back into `$z` for the next loop.

We then also output the second string literal concatenated with whatever is still left in `$z`.

This keeps the current specification intact, in that capital vowels are distinguished from lowercase vowels, since `-creplace` is explicitly case sensitive.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\briefest-code-find-vowels.ps1
Enter string: LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecuteurAdipscingElit!
Vowel Count: a: 0, e: 4, i: 4, o: 4, u: 3
Remaining characters: LrmIpsmDlrStAmtCnsctrAdpscngElt!

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\briefest-code-find-vowels.ps1
Enter string: ProgrammingPuzzlesAndCodeGolf
Vowel Count: a: 1, e: 2, i: 1, o: 3, u: 1
Remaining characters: PrgrmmngPzzlsAndCdGlf
```

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 133 bytes

```
(a()|e()|i()|o()|u()|.)+
Enter string: $&¶Vowel count: a: $#2, e: $#3, i:$#4, o:$#5, u:$#6¶Remaining characters: $&
(?<=s:.+)[aeiou]
<empty-line>
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KGEoKXxlKCl8aSgpfG8oKXx1KCl8LikrCkVudGVyIHN0cmluZzogJCbCtlZvd2VsIGNvdW50OiBhOiAkIzIsIGU6ICQjMywgaTokIzQsIG86JCM1LCB1OiQjNsK2UmVtYWluaW5nIGNoYXJhY3RlcnM6ICQmCig_PD1zOi4rKVthZWlvdV0K&input=dm93ZWw)

Who is more fit for this challenge than Retina?

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, <strike>181</strike> 177 bytes

[online](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5124473388793856)

```
​{i->r=[:].withDefault{0};o=i.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/[aeiou]/,{r[it]++;''})
"Enter String: $i\nVowel Count: ${r.collect{k,v->"$k: $v"}.join(' ')}\nRemaining characters: $o"}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 184 (counting majuscule vowels) / 180 (ignoring them)

```
puts -nonewline {Enter String: }
flush stdout
gets stdin s
set c {Vowel Count:}
foreach v {a e i o u} {append c " $v: [regsub -all (?i)$v $s {} s]"}
puts "$c\nRemaining Characters: $s"
```

**Explanation**

Most of the code is actually dealing with the strict I/O requirements. The remainder works by doing a regular expression substitution (deletion) on the input string `$s` for every vowel and appending the vowel `$v` and associated number of substitutions to the output string `$c`.

The above code works for mixed-case vowels. Remove the `(?i)` option from the regular expression on the penultimate line for strictly minuscule vowels.

Answer (score 1):

## C# 317 bytes

```
string t=Console.ReadLine();Dictionary v = new Dictionary<char,int>{{'a',0},{'e',0},{'i',0},{'o',0},{'u',0}};string o="";foreach(char c in t){if(v.Keys.Contains(c)){v[c]++;}else{o+=c;}}Console.WriteLine("a: "+v['a']+", e: "+v['e']+", i: "+v['i']+", o: "+v['o']+", u: "+v['u']);Console.WriteLine("Remaining Characters: "+o);
```

Any suggestions, trying to learn to golf with C#. 1KB is obviously way bigger than the other answers though.

Ungolfed:

```
string t=Console.ReadLine();
Dictionary v = new Dictionary<char,int>
{
    {'a',0},
    {'e',0},
    {'i',0},
    {'o',0},
    {'u',0}
};
string o="";
foreach(char c in t)
{
    if(v.Keys.Contains(c))
    {
        v[c]++;
    }
    else
    {
        o+=c;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("a: "+v['a']+", e: "+v['e']+", i: "+v['i']+", o: "+v['o']+", u: "+v['u']);
Console.WriteLine("Remaining Characters: "+o);
```

Comment: Please specifiy an exact byte count in the future, 1 KB is way off from 317 bytes, wich isn't that bad.

Comment: @Bálint Using school computer, it's cryptic getting to the properties of a file for some reason.

Comment: I'd suggest using a regex ( `/[aeiou]/` instead of a dictionary, an use that to match strings

Comment: Just use an online byte counter.

Comment: like http://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Answer (score 1):

## Python 162 Bytes

```
v,s="aeiou",input()
print "String:"+s+"\n"+"Vowel Count"+" ".join([c+":"+str(s.count(c)) for c in v])+"\n"+"Remaining Characters:"+filter(lambda x:v.count(x)<1,s)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 202 bytes

```
print"Enter String: ";t=gets;c=->(x){t.chars.count(x)};a="aeiou".chars
s=a.zip(a.map(&c)).map{|e|"#{e[0]}: #{e[1]}"}.join(", ");r=t.gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")
puts"Vowel Count: #{s}\nRemaining characters: #{r}"
```

Comment: Use `$><<` instead of `print`. Do `s="aeiou".chars.map{|e|"#{e}: #{t.count e}"}*", "` to save a ton of bytes over setting up lambdas and zipping things together. Use `t.tr('aeiou','')` instead of `gsub` to replace, and maybe put it directly into where you have `#{r}` instead of assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 449 bytes

#### Golfed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){std::string x;std::cout<<"Enter String: ",std::cin>>x;int a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0;for(int c=0;c<x.length();c++){switch(x[c]){case 'a':a++;x.erase(c,1);break;case 'e':e++;x.erase(c,1);break;case 'i':i++;x.erase(c,1);break;case 'o':o++;x.erase(c,1);break;case 'u':u++;x.erase(c,1);break;}}std::cout<<"\n Vowel Count: a: "<<a<<", e: "<<e<<", i: "<<i<<", o: "<<o<<", u: "<<u<<"\n Remaining characters: "<<x;}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string x;
    std::cout<<"Enter String: ", std::cin>>x;
    int a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0;
    for(int c = 0; c < x.length(); c++){
        switch(x[c]){
            case 'a':
                a++;
                x.erase(c,1);
                break;
            case 'e':
                e++;
                x.erase(c,1);
                break;
            case 'i':
                i++;
                x.erase(c,1);
                break;
            case 'o':
                o++;
                x.erase(c,1);
                break;
            case 'u':
                u++;
                x.erase(c,1);
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"\n Vowel Count: a: "<<a<<", e: "<<e<<", i: "<<i<<", o: "<<o<<", u: "<<u<<"\n Remaining characters: "<<x;
}
```

Comment: does `case 'u'`, et al really need a space? I don't have a C compiler in front of me right now but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 0):

## C++17, 313 bytes

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;int main(){int n,h[6]={0};string s,v="aeiou",r;cout<<"Enter String: ";getline(cin,s);for(c:s){h[n=v.find(tolower(c))+1]++;if(!n)r+=c;}cout<<"Vowel Count:";n=1;for(c:v)cout<<" "<<c<<": "<<h[n++];cout<<"\nRemaining Characters: "<<r<<"\n";}
```

I suppose I could make this just a function to eliminate standard boilerplate from the byte count.

**Ungolfed**

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  int histogram[6] = {0};   // { (consonants), A, E, I, O, U }
  string source;
  string vowels = "aeiou";  // vowel order matches the histogram
  string consonants;

  cout << "Enter String: ";
  getline( cin, source );

  for (c : source)
  {
    // n ← consonants=0, A=1, E=2, ...
    n = vowels.find( tolower(c) ) + 1;
    histogram[n]++;
    if (!n)
      consonants += c;
  }

  cout<<"Vowel Count:";
  n = 1;
  for (vowel : vowels)
    cout << " " << vowel << ": " << histogram[n++];

  cout << "\nRemaining Characters: " << consonants << "\n";
}
```

**Explanation**

Computes a histogram using the `std::string` lookup functions.

Again, you can eliminate 27 bytes from the count if only minuscule vowels matter. (Remove the first #include and the call to `tolower()`.)

Comment: [275 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY9BS8NAEIXv/orteknYWKmCh2wilNiD4MmCl9rDOtkmA8ls2J2NB/W3x6RY8DQP3sfHGxiGmwZgmq6RoIu1LT6Qw23gGpRat49XMSA1gkxvw2DAirnRSCwoaw8PR90bpCT9CuwXLGRjKY1FF2XmNbjIRSF3xNaL/ZnIhdSN5Q7JJoCUhVSfnE9MZCcgDymekvZA5bg@IdUJfN/fpWpzVCpbUepVCRfnm/u0nahcJM6lpnLzXzOmf5SQRQHzzZcwe5U6XgTv9GqX7cvqqjXewDwynEF/rqX@maYX523/PITYP7nO@T3ytrdcOQoWItvotzUOYX6k2XXIq18 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>134</s> <s>133</s> 131 bytes

Because the other Ruby answer didn't respond to my suggestions, I golfed it down further myself.

-2 bytes from @manatwork

```
$><<"Enter String: "
r=gets.tr v='aeiou',''
puts"Vowel Count: #{v.chars.map{|e|e+": #{$_.count e}"}*', '}
Remaining characters: "+r
```

Comment: `r=gets.tr v='aeiou',''`